# Use column info in another column

Tags: 2010, web-part, column

I am using a standard web part wich relies on html code to render an animated image.
The data to create this image is stored in a column of a custom list, so i have a column with html format.

What i would like to do, is make another column which holds information that i want to load into html colum.

f.e. I have the column with html, and i would add the info from the column image into that column at a certain place:

```
<a href="[Column Image]" target="_blank" style="position:absolute;z-index:4;border:0pt none;outline:medium none;bottom:30px;left:52px;color:rgb(255, 255, 255) ! important">
```

Is this possible?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There has not been a lot of interest in this question, i did fix it however using InfoPath and creating a library template. So for future reference take a look at that